# Topbar links are pushed down on beta sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar, beta-sites

In beta sites text on top bar (e.g. review, help etc.) are pushed down a little bit. To *feel* the difference just open any beta & this meta site in two different tabs and switch between both tabs. I have tested on many beta sites but can't find in themed(launched) sites.

Is this bug or by design?

Looking at it's CSS, the `line-height` value the class `topbar-menu-links` is `1.3` while on themed sites the `line-height` value is 1.0.

[image]

Browsers: Chrome (Version 31.0.1650.63 m), Firefox (Version 26.0); OS: Windows XP

Comment: Yaa, little down in beta .

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be that the top bar is inheriting the global line height set for the `body` element.

On most graduated sites, this is set to 1, which makes the top bar look as (presumably) intended, but on beta sites (and, apparently, a few graduated sites like [Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/)) the line height is 1.3, which causes the text in the top bar to take up a little more vertical space.  It's particularly noticeable (well, if you're looking closely, at least) because the menu triangle icons are positioned relative to the top of the line, and so don't move, whereas the text itself lies on the baseline, which does.

Long story short, here's a quick CSS fix:

```
.topbar { line-height: 1 }
```

This makes the top bar look the same (at least in this respect) on all sites.

**Edit:** This fix is now included in the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch).

Comment: Well, I think I have already mentioned the same solution in my question. :-)

Comment: This got incorporated into the official code at some point. Probably around when Workplace.SE got its design. Either way, fixed!

Comment: @AnnaLear: Thanks for the heads-up! I've removed it from SOUP v1.12, along with a bunch of other fixes that are no longer needed.